# how to split a string with a Delimiter '('?

Tags: c#, split

I need to split this kind of string acd(dsd(fgfg need to split this string by '('(open brace not 'C')?
I have done like below string.split('(') but its considering as a space.
What is the correct method ?

sample i have done

```
string[] Payeename;
Payeename = Stg.CollectrTitle.Split('(');
foreach (string s in Payeename)
{
    Erec.DescValue = s.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: "but its considering as a space" Please expand on what you mean by that.

Comment: What have you tried so far? update your sample code in which part is problem for you

Comment: means that If the string contains any spaces like aabc df( hdd cj then when i use the split method the string splits with the delimiter ' '  not by '('

Comment: @VeeramaniBala  Payeename = Stg.CollectrTitle.Split('(');

Comment: @Akhil, please edit your question with an actual sample that shows how it doesn't work. (Not in the comments). You will need to show the actual value of `Stg.CollectrTitle`, as well as the resulting string array.

Comment: @Akhil, Do you want to remove any spaces in your string first, then split string by delimiter '('? is my understanding is correct?

Comment: @VeeramaniBala no i don't want to remove any spaces. I just want to split it by delimiter'('.

Comment: @Akhil Does poke's answer below is not working for you?

Comment: @VeeramaniBala no its not working for me.

Comment: @Akhil can you edit your question with sample code what you have tried so far on your side? Then only we understand whats your problem and you can receive exact answer....

Comment: @VeeramaniBala this is what i has done
 string[] Payeename;
                    Payeename = Stg.CollectrTitle.Split('(');
                    foreach (string s in Payeename)
                    {
                        Erec.DescValue = s.ToUpper();
                    }
                }
i have updated the question also

Comment: @AkhilAravind: Your example is not *complete* (*"The name 'Stg' does not exist in the current context."*). Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve again.

Comment: Please show the value of `Stg.CollectrTitle`. It would be very helpful if you just used an example like: `string foo = "The string that won't work"; string[] result = foo.Split('(');`. And then show the values in the array that aren't correct.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish in the `foreach` loop? It is just assigning the last string to a variable, which I doubt is your intent (otherwise `Erec.DescValue = s.LastOrDefault().ToUpper()` would be more direct).

Comment: @RufusL **072720(12** is the value of Stg.CollectrTitle

Answer (score 4):

This totally works. Note the upper-case [`Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method.

```
String s = "acd(dsd(fgfg";
var result = s.Split('(');
```

---

```
Erec.DescValue = s.ToUpper();
```

This, in a loop, will repeatedly *overwrite* `Erec.DescValue` with the current item from the loop. So you end up with the very last segment of your result.

Try adding a `Console.WriteLine(s)` inside your loop, so you can see that the string is correctly split.

Comment: @AkhilAravind It is working though, even with spaces in the string. What exactly have you tried? Please expand your question with the actual code *and* the result you are receiving.

Comment: @Akhil, click the link in Heinzi's comment